# Linear model subset selection goodness-of-fit with k-fold cross validation

Tags: subset, cross-validation

I am studying 'An Introduction to Statistical Learning' from James et al (2015). In the experiment section, a script to calculate the goodness-of-fit of different subsets using the k-fold cross validation method.

When I try to plot the error coefficients, I get the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "regsubsets"
```

The script makes too little sense for me to know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me interpret?

```
library(leaps)
library(ISLR)

k=10
set.seed(1)
folds=sample(1:k,nrow(Hitters),replace=TRUE)
cv.errors=matrix(NA,k,19, dimnames=list(NULL, paste(1:19)))

for(j in 1:k){
  best.fit=regsubsets(Salary~.,data=Hitters[folds!=j,],nvmax=19)
  for(i in 1:19){
    pred=predict(best.fit,Hitters[folds==j,],id=i)
    cv.errors[j,i]=mean( (Hitters$Salary[folds==j]-pred)^2)
    }
  }

mean.cv.errors=apply(cv.errors,2,mean)
mean.cv.errors

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(mean.cv.errors,type='b')

reg.best=regsubsets(Salary~.,data=Hitters, nvmax=19)
coef(reg.best,11)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the problem too. Hope you found the answer. If not, here is the answer.

I am sure that you already created the function below.

```
predict.regsubsets <- function(object, newdata, id,...) {
  form <- as.formula(object$call[[2]])
  mat <- model.matrix(form, newdata)
  coefi <- coef(object, id = id)
  xvars <- names(coefi)
  mat[,xvars]%*%coefi
}
```

Now you have to change `pred=predict(best.fit,Hitters[folds==j,],id=i)` to `pred <- predict.regsubsets(best.fit, hitters[folds == j, ], id = i)`

Hope it helped.

Comment: blackknight316, I am currently not really zoomed in on this topic, so I can't give back feedback on your solution. I expect to be working on these types of analysis again soon and then will get back to you. Thank you though for thinking along :)